# Optimising a sudoku solving method

Tags: haskell, sudoku

Making a sudoku solver for an assignment, I have run into a problem in solving blank cells of the sudoku. I can solve cells with unique solutions easily, but when I encounter cells with multiple solutions (in the sudoku's current state), I want to move on to the next blank to try fill in as much of the sudoku as possible before having to "try" values and branch out my solutions accordingly.

My problem is that I do not know how to keep track of which blank value I am up to.

```
blank :: Sudoku -> Pos
blank sudoku
  | elem '.' $ toString sudoku = ( (positInRow `div` 9), (positInRow `mod` 9) )
  | otherwise = error "no blanks"
    where
      positInRow = fromJust $ elemIndex '.' $ toString sudoku

nextBlank :: Sudoku -> Pos -> Pos
nextBlank sudoku (x, y)
  | elem '.' $ drop (x*9+y) $ toString sudoku = blank (fromString $ drop (x*9+y) $ toString sudoku)
  | otherwise = error "no blanks"
```

Here is my attempted solution, but if I try to recursively solve a sudoku, it would get stuck in an infinite loop finding the same "nextBlank" if the original next blank doesn't update a value on the sudoku.

Is there a way to implement this function properly?

Answer (score 1):

First let me wrap your code in some boilerplate, so we can run
something easily:

```
module RandomNoise where

import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

type Pos = (Int, Int)
type Sudoku = String

toString :: Sudoku -> String
toString = id

fromString :: String -> Sudoku
fromString = id

blank :: Sudoku -> Pos
blank sudoku
  | elem '.' $ toString sudoku = (positInRow `div` 9, positInRow `mod` 9)
  | otherwise = error "no blanks"
  where
    positInRow = fromJust $ elemIndex '.' $ toString sudoku

nextBlank :: Sudoku -> Pos -> Pos
nextBlank sudoku (x, y)
  | elem '.' $ drop (x*9+y) $ toString sudoku = blank (fromString $ drop (x*9+y) $ toString sudoku)
  | otherwise = error "no blanks"

testSudoku = "uiae.uiae.uiae.uiae"

firstBlank = blank testSudoku
secondBlankOrNot = nextBlank testSudoku firstBlank
```

If you fire up your ghci and load a file with that content,
you can see, that

```
firstBlank = (0,4)
secondBlank = (0,0)
```

and

```
drop (0*9+4) testSudoku
```

yields

```
".uiae.uiae.uiae"
```

So there are several issues here.

1. You don't drop enough letters from the string. You need to drop the blank specified by the position too.
2. In nextBlank you will need to add the length of the dropped string to the indexes determined in blank before turning them into a position, otherwise you will get some garbage position which is somehow relative to the position of the last blank. I advise to work with indexes into the string representation and calculate the position as a last step in a separate function.